# How to make a TypeScript type guard without any or object?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am using typescript-eslint v3.1.0 and have the following type guard function in TypeScript:

```js
interface JWTPayload {
    sub: number;
}

function isJWTPayload(obj: unknown): obj is JWTPayload {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return false;
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
    const obj2 = obj as object;

    if (!('sub' in obj2)) {
        return false;
    }

    const obj3 = obj2 as JWTPayload;

    if (!Number.isInteger(obj3.sub)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My issue is this: it doesn't feel good to disable a lint rule in what I imagine is a common scenario. Is there a TypeScript pattern that would avoid this?

Some background:

The typescript-eslint rule that is being disabled was introduced in https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/848, in which it is opined that "99.9% of the time, you don't want to use [the "object" type], and the vast majority of codebases won't want to use it". Why might they say this? It seems like it would be used whenever you are validating user input. Is there some other way to do it without a cast to 'any'?

Comment: As the lint message says, *"If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead."*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution without `any` nor assertions:

```
type Message = {
  text: string;
}

function isObject(value: unknown): value is Record<string, unknown> {
  return typeof value === 'object' && value !== null;
}

function isMessage(value: unknown): value is Message {
  return isObject(value) && typeof value["text"] === 'string';
}
```

This works because the first type guard properly detects an object like one would expect. The good part is that `isObject` can be reused in any other type guard.

Note: custom type guards are essentially the same as assertions, so use them with caution. TypeScript doesn't offer a runtime library to map a value to a complex type other than the native `instanceof`. Even `return true` will be completely "valid" but wrong.

Comment: This is what I have settled on using, too, after continuing to play with the problem for a few months. All of my complex type guards are now one-line expressions that consist of `A && B && C && D` where A/B/C/D are guards (AKA the form you have described). The TypeScript compiler takes each guard into account, left-to-right, so they can build on each other. It still does not feel optimal, but it avoids all need for casts/type assertions and the linter is happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` [is a type-guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) itself. So you can just move the logic inside the `if` block:

```js
function isJWTPayload(obj: unknown): obj is JWTPayload {
    if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj) {
        if (!('sub' in obj)) {
            return false;
        }

        const payload = obj as JWTPayload;
        if (Number.isInteger(payload.sub)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFIHUAqAFOBPAGwHs4ATZAbwChlbkBnAVwCMAuZERgW2egG4qAXypUYjEAjDAiIZMHoYc%20YmQAURZgCt24gNYgiAdxABKdhs1z6aLLkIly1OnJjJVYPAAcIRVxeQAvEHIAOQWEJIhyABk0cgWJpQ0znTArqoAhKohTMxRoPFaJolOKWVQEGCMULLwBPQQAmW0wsllCDL0YIWaAMyBPchw1op2KqRNzWluAHLcvFAAdPIAkuAQAObQ6lq9i7nFSc0pFVU1yGBQjI1tKcLOrc6n1bVw9TfCQA)

I would also removed `!('sub' in obj)` check since it doesn't make sense. If `sub` is `undefined`, `Number.isInteger(undefined)` returns `false` as well.

Comment: This is still using assertions, which means it's not completely "safe" either. I'm not sure it's possible without them, but this example is still indistinguishable from a type guard that uses `any`

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't relate to the same linter rule, we had a typeguard that looked something like the example below (which followed directly from the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates)), and it was triggering an eslint warning on the final line for [@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unnecessary-condition/).

```js
type Message = {
  text: string;
}

function isMessage(value: unknown): value is Message {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    return false
  }

  return (value as Message).text !== undefined;
}
```

The rule is implying that this condition is always true, but we know that's not the case. What this made me realize is that we're effectively "tricking" the compiler into thinking `value` is indeed a `Message` in order to let us check whether `value` has a `text` field, so that we can determine whether `value` is a `Message`. This seems a bit odd...

Stepping back, we know that either `value` has a `text` field or it does not. The way I would try to translate that to a type in Typescript is to say `value` is like a `Message`, but with every field being optional. There's actually a utility type [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) which transforms `Type` to a new type with the same fields, but optional!

To me, the following seems more "honest":

```js
function isMessage(value: unknown): value is Message {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    return false
  }

  return (value as Partial<Message>).text !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty clever! Might also consider adding `if (typeof value !== 'object') { return false; }`.

Answer (score 0):

To build on **@David Goldsteins** answer, an even more concise type guard using optional chaining which doesn't trigger eslint;

```
type Message = {
  text: string;
}

const isMessage = (value: unknown): value is Message => {
  return (value as Partial<Message>)?.text !== undefined;
}

console.log(isMessage(undefined));            // false
console.log(isMessage(null));                 // false
console.log(isMessage(0));                    // false
console.log(isMessage('str'));                // false
console.log(isMessage([]));                   // false
console.log(isMessage(new Error()));          // false
console.log(isMessage({text: 'message'}));    // true
```